# Getting null pointer exception on textureview.getSurfaceTexture()?

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I am developing an app which is based on camera,While programming camera api getting null pointer exception on texture.getSurfaceTexture().few days before its was working fine but now its showing null pointer exception and i tried alot but not find a suitable answer to solve this issue.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IView,      

ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener,TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener 

{

MyTextureView mtextureView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mtextureView = new MyTextureView(MainActivity.this);






    mtextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(MainActivity.this);

    Ipresenter = new Presenter();
    Ipresenter.CheckPermission(this);

    setContentView(mtextureView);


}

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


    StartBackgroundThread();
    if (mtextureView.isAvailable()){


    }
    else{


        mtextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
    }


@Override
public void SetCameraId(String CameraId, final ImageReader imageReader, Context context) {


    cameraManager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);


   try {



// This Line

    SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = mtextureView.getSurfaceTexture();

        if (mtextureView.isAvailable()){

            Toast.makeText(context, " available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
        else{


            Toast.makeText(context, "not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }



        cameraManager.openCamera(CameraId, new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {

                // texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());

                SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = mtextureView.getSurfaceTexture();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);


                try {
                    mPreviewRequestBuilder
                            = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    //  e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i(TAG, "onOpened: " + e.getMessage());

                }
                mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
                imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(MainActivity.this, mbackgroundHandler);

                try {
                    cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, imageReader.getSurface()), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {

                            try {
                                cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCaptureStarted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, long timestamp, long frameNumber) {
                                        super.onCaptureStarted(session, request, timestamp, frameNumber);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCaptureProgressed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull CaptureResult partialResult) {
                                        super.onCaptureProgressed(session, request, partialResult);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                                        super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCaptureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull CaptureFailure failure) {
                                        super.onCaptureFailed(session, request, failure);
                                    }
                                }, mbackgroundHandler);
                            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {

                        }
                    }, mbackgroundHandler);
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int i) {

            }


        }, mbackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

}
```

// Texture Class

```
public class MyTextureView extends TextureView {


public MyTextureView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public MyTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}



}
```

//Open Camera Class

```
 public class OpenCamera implements  IOpenCamera {


 Context context;

 HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;
 IPresenter iView;
 private ImageReader mImageReader;

 String TAG =OpenCamera.class.getSimpleName();
 public OpenCamera(Context context) {

    this.context = context;
    mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("BackgroundThread");
    iView =new Presenter();





}





@Override
public void OpenCamera(int width ,int height) {

    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCamera width working: ");

//    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
  //      if (context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    //        return;
      //  }

    //}



    try {

        String CameraId1 = null;
        CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics;

        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

        String CameraIdlist[] = cameraManager.getCameraIdList();

        for (String CameraId : CameraIdlist) {

            CameraId1 = CameraId;
             cameraCharacteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(CameraId);

            Integer facing = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);

            if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {


                continue;

            }
            Log.i(TAG, "part 1: ");
            StreamConfigurationMap map = cameraCharacteristics.get(
                    CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

            if (map == null) {

                continue;
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "part 2: ");



            Size largest = Collections.max(
                    Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)),
                    new Comparator<Size>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(Size lhs, Size  rhs) {

                            return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() -
                                    (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
                        }
                    });

            Log.i(TAG, "part 3: ");

            mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(),
                    ImageFormat.JPEG, /*maxImages*/2);




            Log.i(TAG, "OpenCamera: not null");

            iView.SetCameraId(CameraId1 ,mImageReader,context);



        }








    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

// Presenter Class

```
  public class Presenter implements IPresenter {

  ICheckCameraPermissions CameraCheckPermission;

 //OpenCamera openCamera;

   IView iView;

   boolean GRANTED;
  IOpenCamera iOpenCamera;
  String TAG =Presenter.class.getSimpleName();
  boolean check;

    public Presenter(){
    CameraCheckPermission =new CheckCameraPermission();
    iView =new MainActivity();
    }

   @Override
   public void CheckPermission(Activity context) {

  //   check=  CameraCheckPermission.Check(context );
  iOpenCamera=new OpenCamera(context);


}

 @Override
 public void SetCameraId(String CameraId, ImageReader imageReader             ,Context context) {

    iView.SetCameraId(CameraId, imageReader,context);
}

@Override
public void OpenCamera(int width, int height) {
    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCamera Method: "+width);
     iOpenCamera.OpenCamera(width, height);




        }


    }
```

Comment: Where are you calling `SetCameraId()`? I don't see a call to that method in `MainActivity`, so I suspect that you might be directly instantiating `MainActivity` yourself somewhere.

Comment: @MikeM.i am calling setCameraId the problem is in texture.getSurfaceTexture() whereas method is  working fine   ;

Comment: Yes, but where and how are you calling `SetCameraId()`, exactly? If it's not in `MainActivity` somewhere, then that's likely the root of the issue.

Comment: @MikeM.Yes i have done some changes in above code

Comment: The immediate cause is that `mtextureView` is `null` when you call `SetCameraId`.  That implies that it is being called on the `MainActivity` **before** `onCreate` has initialized that variable.  What you need to do is work out exactly how you got the to `SetCameraId` before the initialization occurred.

Comment: `iView =new MainActivity();` – That is the problem. You cannot instantiate `Activity` classes yourself; the system must handle that. For one thing, they will not be initialized properly, and won't run through the pertinent lifecycle methods, so `onCreate()` never executes, and `mtextureView` never gets set. Also, that new instance would be a completely different instance than the one you see on-screen anyway, right? I didn't go through your setup in detail, but if you need `MainActivity` in `Presenter`, it looks like you can pass it in the constructor, yeah? E.g., `new Presenter(this)`.

Comment: @StephenC you are right this is because of immediate cause. 
i applied all codes in MainActivity then  it starts working .
Thanks brother

Comment: @MikeM.yes you are right its working fine 
Thanks brother